# The most proper way to stop event loop after asyncio.run has been called?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Considering the following code:

```
import asyncio


async def main() -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(2**256)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

What is the most proper way to terminate coroutine main, after it has been called by asyncio.run? When I invoked script and pressed CTRL + C, I saw an ugly traceback.

As I can see from the source code, asyncio.run does a lot of machinery behind the scenes, so I would like to continue using it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you need? asyncio.run already terminates the event loop. What "ugly traceback" did you see?

Comment: MisterMiyagi, I would not like to see the whole traceback message after I pressed CTRL + C, instread, say, I would like to see nothing (or an empty string). I do not think that writing custom signal handler is a good idea, since it would just duplicate asyncio.run logic.

Comment: You can get event loop then schedule the loop close.

Comment: So you are asking how to suppresses `KeyboardInterrupt`?

Comment: Try `loop.call_later(<interval>, loop.close)`.

Comment: I do not think that calling loop.close is a good idea, since I have a pending task, which was initialized by asyncio.run.

Comment: @JohnShallow so you want to run the task in background? Just you're asking how to stop event loop after `asyncio.run` is called.

Answer (score -1):

You probably should handle the SIGINT signal.

```
import asyncio
import functools
import signal

async def main() -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(2**256)

def handler(loop):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, functools.partial(handler, loop=loop))
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The question is how the handler should look like? If you want just close program without exception, use `sys.exit()`

```
def handler(loop):
    sys.exit()
```

However to close everything gracefully, you need to finish every task and stop the loop. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417595/graceful-shutdown-of-asyncio-coroutines) for more insight.