# How to handle graceful shutdown inside of aiohttp coroutines?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to save state into the database of a background aiohttp coroutine before server is shut down. I was thinking of creating a global array of coroutine jobs that need to be finished and do an `await asyncio.gather(*global_jobs)` in the `shutdown` handler.

Is this the proper approach?

Comment: Can you show your proposed code?

Comment: Is this related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417595/graceful-shutdown-of-asyncio-coroutines?

Comment: Do you mean a graceful shutdown of the running script or computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the database of a background aiohttp coroutine" but, as far as cleanup actions at shutdown go, you can:

**Use a signal handler**

```py
import asyncio
import signal


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, my_signal_handler, *additional_args_list)
```

In a Unix setting, if you know that the application is going to be interrupted with a specific signal, you can perform cleanup actions selectively for that signal. See [`loop.add_signal_handler(signum, callback, *args)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler) for further information.

*Note: you can employ a callable class rather than a function as callback, so that the class instance can hold a reference to any resource you wish to interact with during shutdown, e.g. the coroutines you mentioned in your question.*

**Catch asyncio.CancelledError**

```py
import asyncio


async def my_coro():
    try:
        # Normal interaction with aiohttp
        while True:
            pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        cleanup_actions()
```

If you can assume that, at shutdown, the event loop will be stopped cleanly, you can count on your running coroutines to be thrown an `asyncio.CancelledError` before the loop is closed.