# How to Fix Runtime Error: Cannot close a running event loop - Python Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, spyder, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord bot with Python, however whenever I run the sample code here:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('tokenhere')
```

It returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-ea5a13e5703d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Pictures/rito_bot.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Pictures')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 703, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Pictures/rito_bot.py", line 22, in <module>
    client.run('token')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 595, in run
    _cleanup_loop(loop)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 97, in _cleanup_loop
    loop.close()

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 94, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")

RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

Every other line seems to run just fine, but without the last line it doesn't connect to the server, which makes it useless.

Note: I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862318/python-asyncio-runtimeerror-cannot-close-a-running-event-loop), however OP's solution doesn't seem applicable to my situation.

Comment: What version are you using?  Run `print(discord.__version__)`.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) To run async code in our consoles you first need to install the [nest_asyncio](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio) package and then call it in our consoles before running any of your code.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba Thank you so much dude! Can you add it as an answer so I can accept your question? Again, Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that fixed your problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Spyder maintainer here) To run async code in our consoles you first need to install the [nest_asyncio](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio) package and then call it before running any of your code as described on its Readme.

Comment: The correct approach is given here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243393/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running-debugging-aiohttp-asyncio-a

Check for a running event loop and if there is one, use await otherwise run.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem trying to run Discord examples on `Jupyter Notebook`. Moving to plain python script solved it for me.

Comment: it turns out that this problem seems to be unique to anaconda, so this would work. i was looking for a solution for all compilers, so switching to plain Python script wouldn't really be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

maybe import this , will help .as it works for me.

if you use jupytet notebook or google colab you will face this error

import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()