# Spyder: Cannot close a running event loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently checking out the Python discord wrapper [found here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but it doesn't seem to work due to the above mentioned error. I tried calling the `nest_asyncio.apply()` before running the `client.run()` function but it doesn't seem to work either as mentioned in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639751/how-to-fix-runtime-error-cannot-close-a-running-event-loop-python-discord-bot). This question is possibly a duplicate but couldn't add a comment in the previous one.

I tried this:

```
nest_asyncio.apply()
client = discord.Client()
client.run(bot_token)
```

as well as this to no avail:

```
client = discord.Client()
nest_asyncio.apply(client.run(bot_token))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a similar, if not the same issue a few months ago, and what I found on a [comment to a github issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/710#issuecomment-395609297) ultimately led to the following:

```py
class DiscordAccessor:
    '''class to handle discord authentication and async loop handling
    Attributes
    ----------
        dc_coroutine
            the coroutine to start the client
        dc_thread
            the thread to keep the coroutine alive
    Methods
    -------
        start_loop
            starts the async loop'''
    dc_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    client = discord.Client(loop=dc_loop)

    def __init__(self):
        self.dc_coroutine = DiscordAccessor.client.start('YOUR_TOKEN')
        self.dc_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_loop,
                                args=(self.dc_loop, self.dc_coroutine))
        self.dc_thread.start()

    def start_loop(self, loop, coro):
        '''starts the async loop
        Parameters
        ----------
            loop
                the asyncio loop
            coro
                the coroutine'''
        loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

This class wraps the discord client into it's own thread and event loop. You'd call your client something like:

```py
dc = DiscordAccessor()
dc.client.whatever_you_want_to_call()
```

Comment: After making some changes to make it work for Python 3(Thread module has been deprecated), I still get the same error on Spyder.

Comment: What Python version and discord.py-version are you running? I've been using this with Python 3.6 and discord.py 1.2.5

Comment: Python 3.7.4 with discord.py 1.3.2

Comment: I probably should point out I've been using `threading.Thread`, forgot to add my imports. That said, I have never tested this solution with any other setup than the one I mentioned