# Why do I get error when I am trying to run my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new in python but, I wanted to make a discord bot. I've already seen some solutions that didn't help me.My problem is that I am getting an error(RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop) when i am trying to run this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Here we go!')
    
client.run('qXfSXVL.......ww4FeCB6H.....Sw6')
```

P.S. I am using spyder anaconda with python 3.7 and I've tried to install nest_asyncio.

EDIT:
I did everything that you said and it keep writing that error.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639751/how-to-fix-runtime-error-cannot-close-a-running-event-loop-python-discord-bot

Comment: Yes, and that didn't work!

Comment: @DanilaGoodGamer [Be nice](/conduct). And what do you mean it didn't work? What did you try? Could you not install `nest_asyncio`? Did you get a different error? Please [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Fix Runtime Error: Cannot close a running event loop - Python Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639751/how-to-fix-runtime-error-cannot-close-a-running-event-loop-python-discord-bot)

Comment: actually... no. sory

Comment: Maybe(as i mentioned)it is because I am using spyder anaconda 3 with python 3.7

Comment: also maybe because i have other bots in the server

Comment: can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install nest_asyncio.

Linux:

```
pip3 install nest_asyncio
```

Windows:

```
pip install nest_asyncio
```

Then run nest_asyncio code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Here we go!')
    
client.run('qXfSXVL.......ww4FeCB6H.....Sw6')
```

Same question: [How to Fix Runtime Error: Cannot close a running event loop - Python Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639751/how-to-fix-runtime-error-cannot-close-a-running-event-loop-python-discord-bot)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In cases where this question is identical to another question, the recommended course of action is to flag this one as a duplicate instead of adding an answer.