# Handling interrupts in asyncio jobs running in separate processes with done callbacks

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, event-loop, process-pool

I'm running a large number of CPU-bound computations in separate processes and want to perform some callback as each job finishes. To do this I'm combining `asyncio` with a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, and I'm setting a callback on each `Future` via `add_done_callback`:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
import time
import random

def run_job(job):
    length = random.randrange(1, 10)
    time.sleep(length)
    return f"slept for {length} s"

def on_complete(future, job):
    print(f"Finished computing job {job}: {future.result()}")

async def run_jobs(executor, jobs):
    """Run computations in separate processes and update results asynchronously."""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []

    print(f"Scheduling {len(jobs)} jobs")
    for job in jobs:
        future = loop.run_in_executor(
            executor,
            run_job,
            job,
        )
        future.add_done_callback(
            partial(on_complete, job=job)
        )

        tasks.append(future)

    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jobs = [str(jobnum) for jobnum in range(1, 10)]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        asyncio.run(run_jobs(executor, jobs))
```

This works well, except that if the computation is interrupted e.g. by a `KeyboardInterrupt` then `stderr` gets spammed with messages from each subprocess saying `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532304/2251982) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765606/whats-the-correct-way-to-clean-up-after-an-interrupted-event-loop) suggests to use the Python 3.7+ `asyncio.run` function since it handles clean-up after interrupts, but this appears not to work for jobs running in separate processes.

The traceback from one of the `RuntimeError`s emitted after a `KeyboardInterrupt` points to a possible cause:

```
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7fd4f679ea60 state=finished returned str>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 328, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  ...other stuff...
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

<strike>My guess is that when `asyncio.run` cancels the running tasks while handling the interrupt, the callbacks get called within each `Future`'s separate process, but `asyncio.run` closes the event loop before these callbacks run since it isn't blocked by the callback execution.</strike>

EDIT: I commented out the `add_done_callback` block while the futures get created, and this doesn't change the outcome - suggesting the problem is nothing to do with the callbacks after all, and instead the same problem as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921330/how-to-terminate-long-running-computation-cpu-bound-task-in-python-using-async).

Comment: Ah, if I comment out the `add_done_callback` stuff, the same error is still present. This suggests the problem is the same as that discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921330/how-to-terminate-long-running-computation-cpu-bound-task-in-python-using-async) after all, and not specific to my callback code.
Mods: should I delete or close this question?